# Are the skills learned for a degree in Computer Engineering helpful in learning Quantum Computing?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, entanglement

Next year, I will be a senior Computer Engineering student. Saying that, I have studied computer organization, electrical circuits, electronics and data structures.

Our university provides an opportunity to get a concentration on quantum computing.

So, my question is:
Are the subjects I mentioned helpful in learning about quantum computing?
Are there other prerequisites that may also be helpful?

Comment: Yes. From computer science perspective, you need a solid understanding of linear algebra, abstract algebra and basic of Probability theory, then you can read any beginner textbooks in quantum computing such as Mermin's textbook. The deeper you go in this field, the more you need other topics in math (like lie algebra, topology, complexity, or information theory, etc.)

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to QCSE!  The way your question is currently written, it can be kinda opinion-based.  Can you consider revising your question along the lines of "how much of knowledge of computer engineering is useful in understanding quantum computing?" or something, which might be more constructive?

Comment: They are obviously very helpful, they are actually a requirement...

Comment: The discussion here reminds of the [famous parable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). "Quantum Computing" is a collective name for a whole bunch of disciplines. Quantum hardware (mostly experimental physics and engineering); Quantum information (math from advanced linear algebra to category theory) and algorithms; Applications (various sorts of theoretical physics). Depending on where you want to go, your knowledge will have different value. If you go into developing working prototypes, a huge part of it will come in handy. If you go to theory - mostly linear algebra.

Answer (score 3):

For quantum computing you will need some bases in linear algebra and probability theory. [This book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information/01E10196D0A682A6AEFFEA52D53BE9AE) has pretty much everything you need to know about quantum information, and it covers the bases you need to understand the field, i.e. chapter 2 *Introduction to quantum mechanics* is about Linear Algebra and there is also a little bit of proba theory on the appendix 1. [The Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html) also gives you a good view of the background you need by doing examples at the same time.

If you need something else feel free to ask! :)